# How to Display Month Wise Data from Year in SQL Server without date in output

Tags: sql-server-2014

I'm trying to get data months wise for that I had written Query like this but not getting the result as i want

```html
SET dateformat dmy 

SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT 'Apr'                                 AS xData, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * assemblywt ), 0))  AS asswt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * [waxwt/pcs] ), 0)) AS waxwt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * corewt ), 0))      AS corewt, 
               '2015'                                AS 'Year' 
        FROM   tdcwaxweight 
        WHERE  Month(dt) = '04' 
               AND Year(dt) = '2015' 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'May'                                 AS xData, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * assemblywt ), 0))  AS asswt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * [waxwt/pcs] ), 0)) AS waxwt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * corewt ), 0))      AS corewt, 
               '2015'                                AS 'Year' 
        FROM   tdcwaxweight 
        WHERE  Month(dt) = '05' 
               AND Year(dt) = '2015' 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Jun'                                 AS xData, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * assemblywt ), 0))  AS asswt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * [waxwt/pcs] ), 0)) AS waxwt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * corewt ), 0))      AS corewt, 
               '2015'                                AS 'Year' 
        FROM   tdcwaxweight 
        WHERE  Month(dt) = '06' 
               AND Year(dt) = '2015' 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Jul'                                 AS xData, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * assemblywt ), 0))  AS asswt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * [waxwt/pcs] ), 0)) AS waxwt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * corewt ), 0))      AS corewt, 
               '2015'                                AS 'Year' 
        FROM   tdcwaxweight 
        WHERE  Month(dt) = '07' 
               AND Year(dt) = '2015' 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Aug'                                 AS xData, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * assemblywt ), 0))  AS asswt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * [waxwt/pcs] ), 0)) AS waxwt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * corewt ), 0))      AS corewt, 
               '2015'                                AS 'Year' 
        FROM   tdcwaxweight 
        WHERE  Month(dt) = '08' 
               AND Year(dt) = '2015' 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Sep'                                 AS xData, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * assemblywt ), 0))  AS asswt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * [waxwt/pcs] ), 0)) AS waxwt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * corewt ), 0))      AS corewt, 
               '2015'                                AS 'Year' 
        FROM   tdcwaxweight 
        WHERE  Month(dt) = '09' 
               AND Year(dt) = '2015' 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Oct'                                 AS xData, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * assemblywt ), 0))  AS asswt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * [waxwt/pcs] ), 0)) AS waxwt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * corewt ), 0))      AS corewt, 
               '2015'                                AS 'Year' 
        FROM   tdcwaxweight 
        WHERE  Month(dt) = '10' 
               AND Year(dt) = '2015' 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Nov'                                 AS xData, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * assemblywt ), 0))  AS asswt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * [waxwt/pcs] ), 0)) AS waxwt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * corewt ), 0))      AS corewt, 
               '2015'                                AS 'Year' 
        FROM   tdcwaxweight 
        WHERE  Month(dt) = '11' 
               AND Year(dt) = '2015' 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Dec'                                 AS xData, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * assemblywt ), 0))  AS asswt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * [waxwt/pcs] ), 0)) AS waxwt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * corewt ), 0))      AS corewt, 
               '2015'                                AS 'Year' 
        FROM   tdcwaxweight 
        WHERE  Month(dt) = '12' 
               AND Year(dt) = '2015' 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Jan'                                 AS xData, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * assemblywt ), 0))  AS asswt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * [waxwt/pcs] ), 0)) AS waxwt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * corewt ), 0))      AS corewt, 
               '2016'                                AS 'Year' 
        FROM   tdcwaxweight 
        WHERE  Month(dt) = '01' 
               AND Year(dt) = '2016' 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Feb'                                 AS xData, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * assemblywt ), 0))  AS asswt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * [waxwt/pcs] ), 0)) AS waxwt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * corewt ), 0))      AS corewt, 
               '2016'                                AS 'Year' 
        FROM   tdcwaxweight 
        WHERE  Month(dt) = '02' 
               AND Year(dt) = '2016' 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Mar'                                 AS xData, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * assemblywt ), 0))  AS asswt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * [waxwt/pcs] ), 0)) AS waxwt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * corewt ), 0))      AS corewt, 
               '2016'                                AS 'Year' 
        FROM   tdcwaxweight 
        WHERE  Month(dt) = '03' 
               AND Year(dt) = '2016') AS tbl 
ORDER  BY year
```

and got this result
[image: Got This REsult]

But I Actually Want Like this (Year and Month Wise)
[image: Actual what i want]

so what I have to do for that let me know where I have to change in my query
can anyone please help me ..thanx in advance

Comment: Are you trying to sort by year first and then by month?

Comment: yes exactly i want

Comment: What about adding `MONTH(dt)` to orderby clause? But you will have to select the `dt` or at least `MONTH(dt)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET dateformat dmy 

SELECT 
xData,
asswt,
waxwt,
corewt
'Year'
FROM   (SELECT 'Apr'                                 AS xData, 
                 1                                   AS xNum,
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * assemblywt ), 0))  AS asswt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * [waxwt/pcs] ), 0)) AS waxwt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * corewt ), 0))      AS corewt, 
               '2015'                                AS 'Year' 
        FROM   tdcwaxweight 
        WHERE  Month(dt) = '04' 
               AND Year(dt) = '2015' 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'May'                                 AS xData, 
                 2                                   AS xNum,
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * assemblywt ), 0))  AS asswt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * [waxwt/pcs] ), 0)) AS waxwt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * corewt ), 0))      AS corewt, 
               '2015'                                AS 'Year' 
        FROM   tdcwaxweight 
        WHERE  Month(dt) = '05' 
               AND Year(dt) = '2015' 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Jun'                                 AS xData, 
                 3                                   AS xNum,
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * assemblywt ), 0))  AS asswt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * [waxwt/pcs] ), 0)) AS waxwt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * corewt ), 0))      AS corewt, 
               '2015'                                AS 'Year' 
        FROM   tdcwaxweight 
        WHERE  Month(dt) = '06' 
               AND Year(dt) = '2015' 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Jul'                                 AS xData, 
                 4                                   AS xNum,
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * assemblywt ), 0))  AS asswt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * [waxwt/pcs] ), 0)) AS waxwt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * corewt ), 0))      AS corewt, 
               '2015'                                AS 'Year' 
        FROM   tdcwaxweight 
        WHERE  Month(dt) = '07' 
               AND Year(dt) = '2015' 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Aug'                                 AS xData, 
                 5                                   AS xNum,
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * assemblywt ), 0))  AS asswt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * [waxwt/pcs] ), 0)) AS waxwt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * corewt ), 0))      AS corewt, 
               '2015'                                AS 'Year' 
        FROM   tdcwaxweight 
        WHERE  Month(dt) = '08' 
               AND Year(dt) = '2015' 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Sep'                                 AS xData, 
                6                                    AS xNum,
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * assemblywt ), 0))  AS asswt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * [waxwt/pcs] ), 0)) AS waxwt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * corewt ), 0))      AS corewt, 
               '2015'                                AS 'Year' 
        FROM   tdcwaxweight 
        WHERE  Month(dt) = '09' 
               AND Year(dt) = '2015' 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Oct'                                 AS xData, 
                 7                                   AS xNum,
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * assemblywt ), 0))  AS asswt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * [waxwt/pcs] ), 0)) AS waxwt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * corewt ), 0))      AS corewt, 
               '2015'                                AS 'Year' 
        FROM   tdcwaxweight 
        WHERE  Month(dt) = '10' 
               AND Year(dt) = '2015' 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Nov'                                 AS xData, 
                 8                                   AS xNum,
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * assemblywt ), 0))  AS asswt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * [waxwt/pcs] ), 0)) AS waxwt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * corewt ), 0))      AS corewt, 
               '2015'                                AS 'Year' 
        FROM   tdcwaxweight 
        WHERE  Month(dt) = '11' 
               AND Year(dt) = '2015' 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Dec'                                 AS xData, 
                9                                    AS xNum,
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * assemblywt ), 0))  AS asswt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * [waxwt/pcs] ), 0)) AS waxwt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * corewt ), 0))      AS corewt, 
               '2015'                                AS 'Year' 
        FROM   tdcwaxweight 
        WHERE  Month(dt) = '12' 
               AND Year(dt) = '2015' 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Jan'                                 AS xData, 
               10                                    AS xNum,
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * assemblywt ), 0))  AS asswt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * [waxwt/pcs] ), 0)) AS waxwt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * corewt ), 0))      AS corewt, 
               '2016'                                AS 'Year' 
        FROM   tdcwaxweight 
        WHERE  Month(dt) = '01' 
               AND Year(dt) = '2016' 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Feb'                                 AS xData, 
               11                                    AS xNum,
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * assemblywt ), 0))  AS asswt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * [waxwt/pcs] ), 0)) AS waxwt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * corewt ), 0))      AS corewt, 
               '2016'                                AS 'Year' 
        FROM   tdcwaxweight 
        WHERE  Month(dt) = '02' 
               AND Year(dt) = '2016' 
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Mar'                                 AS xData,
               12                                    AS xNum,       
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * assemblywt ), 0))  AS asswt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * [waxwt/pcs] ), 0)) AS waxwt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * corewt ), 0))      AS corewt, 
               '2016'                                AS 'Year' 
        FROM   tdcwaxweight 
        WHERE  Month(dt) = '03' 
               AND Year(dt) = '2016') AS tbl 
ORDER  BY year and xNum
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying ORDER BY only on year. In order to achieve the expected result you have to

1. Add month numbers in sub query with `CONVERT(INT, MONTH(dt)) AS Month_Number`
2. Add `Month_Number` in `ORDER BY` clause as `ORDER BY year, Month_Number`

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT 'Apr'                                 AS xData, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * assemblywt ), 0))  AS asswt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * [waxwt/pcs] ), 0)) AS waxwt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * corewt ), 0))      AS corewt, 
               '2015'                                AS 'Year',
               ------------------------------------------------
               CONVERT(INT, MONTH(dt)) AS Month_Number 
               ------------------------------------------------
        FROM   tdcwaxweight 
        WHERE  Month(dt) = '04' 
               AND Year(dt) = '2015'
        GROUP BY MONTH(dt)

        UNION 
        SELECT 'May'                                 AS xData, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * assemblywt ), 0))  AS asswt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * [waxwt/pcs] ), 0)) AS waxwt, 
               Sum(Isnull(( qty * corewt ), 0))      AS corewt, 
               '2015'                                AS 'Year',
               ------------------------------------------------
               CONVERT(INT, MONTH(dt)) AS Month_Number 
               ------------------------------------------------
        FROM   tdcwaxweight 
        WHERE  Month(dt) = '05' 
               AND Year(dt) = '2015'
        GROUP BY MONTH(dt)


        -- Remaining Code --

) AS tbl 
ORDER  BY year, Month_Number
```

Comment: it gives me error like " Column 'tdcwaxweight.DT' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. "

Comment: Add `MONTH(dt)` in either `GROUP BY MONTH(dt)` or in an aggregate such as `MAX(CONVERT(INT, MONTH(dt)))`